# Changing research field mid Ph.D. vs Leaving Institute with no Ph.D

Tags: phd, advisor, physics, research-topic

I am doing my Ph.D. (physics) in a country where there is a countrywide Ph.D. entrance exam. I appeared for the entrance exam and got into (arguably) the best institute in my country. This was 3 years ago. The problem is that the institute decides our department before the entrance exam. After my 3 years B.Sc, I did not know any better and applied for the Experimental High Energy Physics Department. After joining, I realised that I did not like HEP that much and wanted to change my department. But my institute would not let me do that.

I finally found a supervisor in our department who works in a lot of different topics like Optics and Quantum Computation. I joined his lab and worked with him for the last one and a half year during my coursework. Two months ago, I registered for my Ph.D. under the same supervisor.

Recently, the conditions in our lab deteriorated a lot. There is a general feeling of depression and anxiety among the other students. Work is going **really** slowly because of the following reasons:

1. All the students are working in individual experimental project that have no overlap with one another.
2. The supervisor is a big-shot and has his own research interests. And 
   he is not particularly interested in our work. (This is a feedback I got from all my lab seniors).
3. We have to do **all** administrative and engineering work related to our project by ourselves.
4. There are **no** publications from our lab in the last 5 years. I was made to believe that it was the students fault that there was no publication. But the more I see, the more I realise that this is the rule and not the exception. I mean, all the students can't be at fault. I know that this should have been a red flag but as I said before, I was made to believe something else.

I am realising now that staying in the lab is not an option. Even my seniors are contemplating on leaving the lab. I have two options now.

1. Leave the lab and join someone else in the same department. Note that there is no one in our department who works on a similar field.
2. Leave the institute altogether. Then I have to do a one-year M.Sc thesis project before leaving. **There is only one other group in our country that does a similar work and they are already full. Also, it is really hard to get into the labs in other countries even with my research experience.**

I am planning to follow the first option and join a different group in our department. This group works on a field that is neither HEP nor my present field.

So my question is; **Is it wise to change the field mid Ph.D.? Or should I risk it and leave with M.Sc and apply for Ph.D. abroad?** In either case, I will have to start from scratch and my one and a half year of work would be for nothing.

***TL;DR: Due to problems in our current lab, should I leave our lab and join another group who works on entirely different subject or leave my institute altogether and apply in universities abroad (which is difficult).***

P.S. I have about 4 years of institute funding left, if I plan on staying in the institute.

Comment: "There are no publications from our lab in the last 5 years." *Run, Forrest, run!*

Comment: We can't really tell you what to do. (Well, we can tell you probably shouldn't stay in a lab where no one has published in the last 5 years!) You seem to be well-informed about the upsides and downsides of your choices, so what's left is a personal decision that really depends on your tolerance for risk, or your tolerance for working on a subject that's not your core interest. (Although I don't know your country or your field, so I can't say if your perceptions are accurate - maybe you want to change your question to that?)

Comment: @lighthouse keeper: In case some here don't recognize your reference, which I liked by the way --- [*Run, Forrest, run!*](https://www.google.com/search?q=Run%2C+Forrest%2C+run%21)